# Interval of convergence problem: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin^2(n))x^n$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that we have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sin^2(n))x^n$$ and we want to find the radius of convergence. This was a problem I ran into a while back in calc 2, and I never got it sorted out. Really bummed me out too. So if we apply the ratio test we have : $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left |\frac{\sin^2(n+1)x^{n+1}}{\sin^2(n)x^n} \right | = \lim_{n \to \infty} |x| \left |\frac{\sin^2(n+1)}{\sin^2(n)} \right| $$

But how do we deal with this term. It will diverge right? I tried to simplify the $\sin^2$ terms by using the $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2} -\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}$ for the top and the bottom but it seems to be making more work for myself. Is there no such radius of convergence and the ratio test just says that this diverges??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $-1 < x < 1$, the series converges *absolutely*, so the series converges. For $|x| \geq 1$, we should have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin^{2}(n) =0$ if the series converges. However, for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists at least one $n$ with $\frac{\pi}{4} + k\pi < n < \frac{3\pi}{4} + k\pi$ since the length of the interval $[\frac{\pi}{4} + k\pi, \frac{3\pi}{4} + k\pi]$ is $\pi /2$, which is larger than 1. This gives $\sin^{2}(n) > 1/2$, so we have infinitely many $n$ with $\sin^{2}(n) > 1/2$ and the limit above fails.